# Mested attributes with cocoon gem are not saving in the form and showing in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

When I enter data into the form association (lines) and save the form.  The information is not saving and is gone when I got back to edit the form.  Information is also not showing in the view.  Everything seems to checkout on my end but I feel like I'm missing one simple thing.

How can I get the nested attributes to save to the database?

Controller

```
    class LyricsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_lyric, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @lyric = Lyric.published.order("created_at DESC").take(1)
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @lyric = Lyric.new
    end

    def create
        @lyric = Lyric.new(lyric_params)
        if @lyric.save
            redirect_to @lyric, notice: "Successfully created new lyric"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @lyric.update(lyric_params)
            redirect_to @lyric
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy
        @lyric.destroy
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Successfully deleted recipe"
    end

    private

    def lyric_params
        params.require(:lyric).permit(:title, :artist, :song, :link, :published_at, :status, :verse, lines_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
    end

    def find_lyric
        @lyric = Lyric.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Model

```
    class Lyric < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lines

    scope :draft, ->{where(published_at: nil)}
    scope :published, ->{where.not(published_at: nil).where("published_at <= ?", Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)"))}
    scope :scheduled, ->{where.not(published_at: nil).where("published_at >= ?", Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)"))}

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :lines, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

     attr_accessor :status

     before_validation :clean_up_status

     def clean_up_status
        self.published_at = case status
                            when "Draft"
                                nil
                            when "Published"
                                Time.zone.now
                            else
                                published_at
                            end
        true
     end
end
```

Model - Associations

```
class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lyric
end
```

Show View

```
<h1> <%= @lyric.title %></h1>
<p><%= @lyric.artist %></p>

        <ul>
        <% @lyric.lines.each do |line| %>
            <li> <%= line.name %></li>

            <% end %>

        </ul>
<p><%= @lyric.published_at %></p>



    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_lyric_path %> | 


    <%= link_to 'Destroy', lyric_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Form

```
<%= simple_form_for @lyric, html: {multipart:true} do |f| %>

<%= f.error_notification %>

 <%= f.input :title, label: "Title" %>


   <%= f.input :artist, label: "Artist" %>


  <%= f.input :song, label: "Song" %>

  <%= f.input :link, label: "Link", hint: "Link to Track" %>

   <%= f.simple_fields_for :lines do |line| %>

      <%= render 'line_fields', f: line %>

    <% end %>

    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Line', f, :lines %>

      <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %>
    <%= f.select :status, ["Draft", "Published", "Scheduled"], selected: status_for(@lyric) %>
  </div>

      <div class="field published-field">
    <%= f.label :published_at, "Publish At" %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :published_at %>
  </div>


<%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class: "post-button" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: the code causing syntax error  (in `lyric_params`, visible on screenshot) is different than the one you posted. Please update error message or code to the latest version.

Comment: I fixed the syntax error but nested attributes still not saving in the form.